# I need to run tcl script with options from another tcl script

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl script `drakon_gen.tcl` . I am running it, from another script `run.tcl` like this:

```
source "d:\\del 3\\drakon_editor1.22\\drakon_gen.tcl"
```

When I run `run.tcl` I have following output:

```
This utility generates code from a .drn file.
Usage: tclsh8.5 drakon_gen.tcl <options>
Options:
-in <filename>          The input filename.
-out <dir>              The output directory. Optional.
```

Now I need to add to `run.tcl` options that are in the output. I tried many ways but I receive errors. What is the right way to add options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you source a script into a tcl interpreter, you are evaluating the script file in the context of the current interpreter. If it was written to be a standalone program you may run into problems with conflicting variables and procedures in the global namespace. One way to avoid that is to investigate the use of slave interpreters (see the [`interp`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/interp.htm) command) to provide a separate environment for the child script.

In your specific example it looks like you just need to provide some command line arguments. These are normally provided by the [`argv`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/UserCmd/tclsh.htm#M8) variable which holds a list of all the command line arguments. If you define this list before sourcing the script you can feed it the required command line. eg:

```
set original_argv $argv
set argv [list "--optionname" "value"]
source $additional_script_filename
set argv $original_argv
```

Comment: You might also need to set up the `argc` and `argv0` global variables, though they're much more rarely used.